# Proving Properties of Integers from the Definition as the Smallest Inductive Set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, integers, axioms, foundations

I am more or less familiar with constructions of the real number system starting from the Peano axioms for $\mathbb{N}$ and proceeding to $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{R}$.

Apostol's Calculus, however, starts with the field axioms for $\mathbb{R}$ (including completeness), and then *defines* $\mathbb{N}$ as the smallest inductive set in $\mathbb{R}$, as follows:

- A set $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is said to be inductive if $1\in\mathcal{S}$ and for all $x\in\mathcal{S}$, $x+1\in\mathcal{S}$.
- A real number is called a positive integer if it belongs to every inductive set.

Later on he says:

> In a thorough treatment of the real-number system, it would be
>   necessary at this statge to prove certain theorems about integers. For
>   example, the sum, difference, or product of two integers is an
>   integer, but the quotient of two integers need not be an integer.
>   However, we shall not enter into the details of such proofs.

My questions are:

1. How common is it to define the $\mathbb{N}$ in this way, rather than
   defining $\mathbb{R}$ constructively from $\mathbb{N}$?
2. I would be interested to see how the proofs of the above statements
   would look like, as well as something like "if $n$ and $n+1$ are
   positive integers, there is no positive integer $m$ such that
   $n<m<n+1$".

Comment: Once you show that $\Bbb N$ satisfies Peano Axioms, everything follows.

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed Apostol's treatment of $\mathbb N$ is pretty unusual. Perhaps the reason he wanted to do it this way is so as to emphasize the fact that $\mathbb N$ is literally a *subset* of $\mathbb R$ rather than being isomorphic or even naturally isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R$.  The problem is that in the usual construction of everything from $\emptyset$ in set theory, a natural number has finite von Neumann rank (namely, "itself") whereas each real number has von Neumann rank $\omega+1$, so strictly speaking $\mathbb N\not\subseteq\mathbb R$.  See related discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2332559/72694).